# Update rails database entire column with complex calculation function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails table. (normalusers)=> id, parent_id, Height. I have added the height column afterward. Now I want to add value to it. Is there any way I can achieve this? I have tried migration but it is not updating heights. I think functions do not work in migration. After migration, all the rows have the value of height same as before.

```
class Latest < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]

  def change
      i = 1
    loop do
          i += 1
          puts i
          record=Normaluser.find(i)
          record.height=get_height(record)
          record.save!
          if i == 39
            break       # this will cause execution to exit the loop
          end
    end
  end
  def get_height(record)
      maxHeight=0
      Normaluser.where(pid: record.id).each do |f|
          tempHeight=get_height(f)
          if tempHeight > maxHeight
              maxHeight=tempHeight
          end     
      end
      return maxHeight
  end
end
```

Comment: Please mention what is not working? Is there any error that you are facing?

Comment: @Gautam is this understandable?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong in writing functions. I think you should debug to see that the value received from `get_height` function is correct.

Comment: @Gautam Where to see the output of put statement? It is not visible in the terminal.

Comment: As suggested by one of the users in the answer below, you should move your logic to a rake task. It will be easier to debug and also makes sense.

Comment: You should be able to see the output of the `puts` statement when you run the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run a one time script to update existing columns of a table is to write a rake task.

in `lib/tasks/` directory, create a file named `update_height.rake`, in that file

```
namespace :update_latest_records do
  desc 'Update height column of existing Latest'
  task height: :environment do
    # your update logic goes here
  end
end
```

Then in project home, run the rake command

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake update_latest_records:height
```

Pass correct `RAILS_ENV` value in each environment, e.g. to update the records in production server it should be `RAILS_ENV=production`

Hope that helps!